# Adding DOMAIN\MACHINE$ to a Local User Group

Tags: networking, security, active-directory, windows-server-2016

I'm following some instructions from a COTS product manual and it gives me these instructions

1. create a local group on my Windows Server 2016 machine
2. add another machine on my network as a member of that group.
3. To complete step four use the format DOMAIN\MACHINE$

The instructions say to add the user in the format **DOMAIN\MACHINE$** but I don't know what that means and I've tried a few variations to see if they work but they don't. The server can't even suggest a match like it does for users like CORPORATE\tpthomp

I've tried:

CORPORATE\MY-SUPER-MACHINE

CORPORATE\MY-SUPER-MACHINE$

**Does anyone know how to add another machine to a local user group on a Windows Server?**

Comment: Well, I just drag and drop the machine into the group. So it depends on what you are using and how you are using it. You should be able to see the name of the machine in Active Directory: the last character of the name should be a $ character. Is the tool you are using check the name against the list of users instead of the list of users and computers? What tool are you using?

Comment: @user165568 I'm logged onto the server using the lusrmgr to create the local group and then adding members from the group properties.

Comment: I didn't know you could manage local computer groups from Active Directory

Comment: @user165568: Are you sure you're not confusing groups with OUs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using "Local Users and Groups" (via `lusrmgr.msc` or `compmgmt.msc`), just make sure that under "Select this object type" you have "Computers" enabled.

[image]
[image]

(Also make sure that under "From this location" you have the correct AD domain selected.)

When entering the computer name in this dialog, you can omit the `DOMAIN\` prefix and the `$` suffix; they'll be automatically resolved. (It's true that computer account names always end with $, but the selection dialog also recognizes "display names", as well as account name prefixes.)

---

The format provided by the instructions is still correct; it's just not required for the lusrmgr GUI.

On the other hand, most command-line tools such as `icacls` or `net` (in fact any tool that doesn't use this "Select" dialog) will only accept an *exact* account name, so the $ suffix is still mandatory in those other tools when adding a computer. The domain may still be optional. For example:

```
net localgroup "My New Group" MY-SUPER-MACHINE$ /add
```

```
net localgroup "My New Group" CORPORATE\MY-SUPER-MACHINE$ /add
```

Comment: Thanks, I was not including computers in my search! Problem solved :) The information about domain and what the $ sign means is also super helpful

Comment: To clarify, it's specifically _computer_ account names that always end with a `$`. (But the dialog can also find the correct object based on just its display name, which doesn't have a $.)